# How to "require" manually installed gems (KDE plasmoid)?

Tags: ruby, kde-plasma, plasmoid

I'm trying to write a Ruby plasmoid for KDE. I need to use barely one rubygem. Whenever I write `require 'dbus'`, it throw me and an error:

`code/main.rb:6:in 'require': no such file to load -- dbus (LoadError)
code/main.rb:6:in '<module:TestApp>'
code/main.rb:5:in '<top (required)>'
/usr/share/apps/plasma_scriptengine_ruby/applet.rb:177:in 'load'
/usr/share/apps/plasma_scriptengine_ruby/applet.rb:177:in 'init'
/usr/share/apps/plasma_scriptengine_ruby/applet.rb:201:in 'constraintsEvent': undefined method 'constraintsEvent' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
/usr/share/apps/plasma_scriptengine_ruby/applet.rb:201:in 'constraintsEvent': undefined method 'constraintsEvent' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`

Actually, normal "ruby main.rb" works well (regarding on "require" part), but testing plasmoid with "plasmoidviewer" fails. Note, that regular gems from standart Ruby installation works well, i.e. `require 'Qt4'` or `require 'yaml'` loads perfectly. I'm using Ruby 1.9.2p180 under Linux.

**09:40 PM - UPDATE:** Richard Dale, one of the QtRuby developers, just fixed this issue a few minutes ago. Next release of KDE will have patched version of QtRuby.

Comment: So your script works when called directly, but not from your test? How are you loading your file from your test file?

Comment: Yes, when called directly, everything's okay, regarding "requires". Everything loads as it should be. However, I don't understand your second question. I have an installed gem, called 'ruby-dbus', which invokes like that: `require 'dbus'`. It invokes perfectly in any ruby script, but not in the _main.rb_. No matter, what gem I require (except of default libraries), it will raise _LoadError_. I test my code with _plasmoidviewer_ utility, which has it's own representations on _main.rb_ file. Every plasmoid written in Ruby should require 'plasma_applet', which will be the first line of your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
   require 'find'
   require 'findUtils'

    Find.find(PATH_WHERE_GEM_IS_INSTALLED) do |path|
      if FileTest.directory?(path)
            $: << File.expand_path(path)
       if File.basename(path)[0] == ?. and File.basename(path) != '.'
          Find.prune
        else
          next
        end
      else
      end
    end
```

and after that you can do

```
require 'dbus'
```

Comment: I have no 'findUtils'. `require 'find'` works good. I think, there should be more clearer way to solve my problem. PATH_WHERE_GEM_IS_INSTALLED is like brute force, isn't it? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
require 'rubygems'
```

?

Comment: Yes, I have. By the way, assuming, that you're a Ruby 1.9 user, automatically means, that rubygems already included by default (try `require 'rubygems'` in irb session, and you'll see, that it will return `false`).